# Issue while Printing Pdf document using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, using

Please suggest me how to print a pdf document using javascript? i tried to load pdf in iframe and in embad object but no use. Actually i need to print a document from local machine which is actually located in server machine. If i write code using c# it is printing at server printer. Please help me am struck here from last one week.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print PDF directly from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript)

Comment: Hi alex thanx for the reply. I already tried in that way but it is not printing total pdf pages insted it is printing first page which am showing in ashx file by converting pdf pages into images using Ghostscript

Comment: Try this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542022/jquery-javascript-or-other-way-silent-print-once-only/30569808#30569808